# wordpress remove email when user register

Tags: php, wordpress, user-registration

I need for user to register on a wordpress site only with username and password .
So a new user comes , wants to register and he is asked to choose a username and a password, no email verification nothing.

Does anyone have any ideea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this codex entry might be what you're looking for: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_new_user_notification

You could overwrite it to simply do nothing, that way the user won't be receiving an e-mail.

If you're unfamiliar with PHP or coding for WordPress it would be helpful to read up on the basics of Theme development here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

In your case, all that needs to be done is this code should be added to the functions.php file of your currently active Theme:

```
if ( !function_exists('wp_new_user_notification') ) {
   function wp_new_user_notification( ) {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I dont think you understood what I want, I want that the registration process for a new user on my site to be based only on username and password I want to remove the email

Comment: Ah, okay! Hm, well I believe e-mail is integrated into the core functionality of users in WordPress. I guess you could make a separate table where you only store username & password. Then use a form that only asks for these two fields.

In that case, you would have to check that same table when the user tries to log in. I'll do some research to see if it's possible to remove e-mail from WordPress users entirely in the mean time!

Comment: I was mistaken! [This](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user) function will allow you to add a user WITHOUT an e-mail address!

Comment: @YasarArafath Use the [wp\_create\_user](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user) function. The e-mail address is optional.